# Problems with redirecting after submitting a form in modal

Tags: php, laravel

This is my controller.

```
class ConsultationController extends Controller
{
    function ConsultationView(){
        return view('/dashboard/home');
    }

    function AddConsultation(Request $request){
        $item_name = $request->input('item_name');
        $description = $request->input('description');
        $material = $request->input('material');
        $quantity = $request->input('quantity');
        $start_date = $request->input('start_date');
        $end_date = $request->input('end_date');

        $isInsertSuccess = Consultation::insert([
            'item_name'=>$item_name,
            'description'=>$description,
            'material'=>$material,
            'quantity'=>$quantity,
            'start_date'=>$start_date,
            'end_date'=>$end_date,
        ]);
   }

}
```

This is my Route.

```
Route::get('/dashboard/home', [ConsultationController::class,'ConsultationView']);
Route::post('consultation_form', [ConsultationController::class,'AddConsultation']);
```

This is the part of my blade file.

```
<form action="consultation_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row d-flex justify-content-center" >
   @csrf
   <!-- Item Name-->
   <div class="col-sm-11 form-floating mb-3 ">
      <input class="form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name" type="text" placeholder="Item name" data-sb-validations="required" required />                      
      <label for="item_name">Item name</label>
      <div class="invalid-feedback" data-sb-feedback="item_name:required">Item name is required.</div>
   </div>
</form>
```

After I sumbit the modal form it should go back to `home` page not to `consultation_form`

[It should go back here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNvs9.png)

[Not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HMpy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `return route` in `AddConsultation()`

```
return redirect(route('/dashboard/home'));
```

Read [Redirecting To Named Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

---

Once your form is submitted to `action="consultation_form"` this URL, the form will save and shows you a blank page. The reason is there are no jobs mentioned afterwards